# Swift Cannot assign to immutable expression of type for protocol enforced variable

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Here is my situation.

```
protocol DataEnforcing{
    var data: String? {get set}
}

class DataSuper {

}

class Data: DataSuper, DataEnforcing {
    var data: String? = ""
}

var ds = Data()
```

If I assign data variable as below it works fine.

```
ds.data = "Some Data"
```

But If I try to assign the same with protocol confirmation checking compiler throw error

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type

```
(ds as? DataEnforcing)?.data = ""
```

Is this documented in swift?

Comment: You have to declare DataEnforcing as a *class protocol*: `protocol DataEnforcing : class { ... }`, otherwise the compiler cannot now that `(ds as DataEnforcing)` is a *reference type*.